# Fragment Not opening with FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

This line gives error and the app stops working.

`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);`

**Main Activity**

```
TimeTable fragment1 = new TimeTable(getSupportFragmentManager());
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**TimeTable** Fragment

```
public class TimeTable extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public TimeTable(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            tab1 t1 = new tab1();
            return t1;
        case 1:
            tab2 t2 = new tab2();
            return t2;
        case 2:
            tab3 t3 = new tab3();
            return t3;

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}//set the number of tabs

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Monday";
        case 1:

            return "Tuesday";
        case 2:

            return "Wednesdey";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: @SagarThakarar `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);`  shows error on `fragment1` (red line)

Comment: is you tab fragments are v4 fragment or an android.app Fragment.

Comment: Because TimeTable  is your FragmentPagerAdapter class and not your fragment class.

Comment: @DrupDesai v4 fragment

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`

Answer (score 0):

if your are use FragmentPagerAdapter so why you are replace fragment ?just set TimeTable.

```
TimeTable mAdapter = new TimeTable (getSupportFragmentManager());
ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

please check link :-http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `ViewPager`.
but this is not the way to use it.

layout having `Viewpager` inside.

```
private ViewPager pager;
private TimeTable timeTable;
```

--> set adapter like this

```
pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vpSettingPages);
t1 = new TimeTable(getSupportFragmentManager())
pager.setAdapter(timeTable);
```

you can see this https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html for reference too.